# Fabric.js - Move object without holding mouse button

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In Fabric.js an object can be moved in the canvas by left-clicking, holding and moving the mouse. In this condition, the selected object follows the mouse's cursor and `object:moving` gets fired. Releasing the left mouse button exits this mode.

Is there a way to change this behavior and have an object enter this mode with different events? For example, click once to have the object follow the cursor (and have the `object:moving` fire correctly) and then click a second time to release the object in it's final position?

I'm hoping to avoid writing this from scratch listening to the "mouse move" event, given that this is already implemented, but just the triggers to enter/exist this mode have to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this by having a variable called `movedObject` which is `null` if no object is moved and contains an object if an object **is** moved. If you click while an object is being moved then it'll set `movedObject` to `null`. If you click while not moving an object then it'll set `movedObject` to an object **if** you clicked one.

I added a listener to `mouse:move` which sets `left` and `top` of `movedObject` to the mouse `x` and `y` (minus `movedObject` `width` and `height` / 2) **if** `movedObject` is not `null`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ut4c25k6/)

Code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setWidth(300);
canvas.setHeight(300);
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 30,
  fill: '#f55',
  top: 100,
  left: 100
});
canvas.add(circle);
circle.hasControls = circle.hasBorders = circle.selectable = false;

var movedObject = null;
canvas.on({
  'mouse:down': function(e) {
    //If an object is selected already it'll be unselected
    if (movedObject !== null) {
        movedObject = null;
    } else {
      //If no object was selected and a click occured on an object it'll now be selected
      if (e.target) {
         movedObject = e.target;
      }
    }
  },
  'mouse:move': function(e) {
    //Moving the object along with mouse cursor
    if (movedObject !== null) {
        movedObject.left = (e.e.clientX - movedObject.width / 2);
        movedObject.top = (e.e.clientY - movedObject.height / 2);
        movedObject.setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly was I was trying to avoid. This is re-implementing most of what's already there in fabric.js, adding overhead and not playing nicely with the event system.

Comment: This might be the only way to do it without modifying the code in fabric.js. I'll give you that (Thus I'm up-voting). But it's not the answer to the question and this was explicitly stated in the question. To clarify even further, this does not fire the "object:moving" event for example, you would have to fire it manually, thus continuing to duplicate code, adding overhead and making it hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Going through the Fabric.js code, the place where an object is marked to be moved is in `canvas.__on_mouse_down(e)` which calls `canvas._setupCurrentTransform(e, target)` (Only place where this method is used). This constructs an object and assigns it to `canvas._currentTransform`. This object, in turn, is used in `canvas.__onMouseMove(e)` to actually move the selected object using `canvas._transformObject(e)`.

The problem is that `canvas.__onMouseUp(e)` calls `canvas._finalizeCurrentTransform()`, so the dragging stops there. Fortunately it also fires "mouse:up" right after. So we can override this in the callback:

```
var mydragging = false;
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
  if (mydragging) {
    mydragging = false;
    canvas.currentTransform = null;
  }
  else {
    canvas._setupCurrentTransform(o.e, o.target);
    mydragging = true;
  }
});
```

This puts the `canvas` in the exact same state as when dragging by holding the mouse button down (before introducing this code), therefore all the built-in behavior remains in place, including firing "object:moving".

Unfortunately `canvas._currentTransform` and `canvas._setupCurrentTransform` are marked as private and cannot be relied upon. Perhaps they are willing to make it public.

Comment: Here is the request to make public: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2753