# Strange Issue with mouse offset when zooming and panning using custom object select function in Fabric.js

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, zooming, selected, panning

I'm trying to get it so that the circle on my canvas is selectable with a mouseclick. Then the user doesn't have to hold down the mouse to move the object. The issue arises when I attempt to zoom or pan. For some reason, instead of following the mouse, the circle seems to reset to the center of the canvas. Then there's a significant offset from the mouse and the circle. Due to this, I can't deselect the circle, or if I can, the handles aren't where I think they should be logically. I started with the code mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35014746/1053106

The strange part I found by a fluke. It seems to be that when I comment out the declaration of the movedObject variable (which keeps track of what I want to move) the zooming function works well, but the panning is still an issue.  But what is also strange is that it zooms correctly even though I get an exception. [See this codepen.](https://codepen.io/morrowsend/pen/QorraJ?editors=0010) Comment and uncomment line 51 to see the behavior. Each time, select the circle, then zoom in with the mousewheel. I have the zoom code from [the Fabric.js tutorial on Zoom and Pan](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5) (even though I can't for the life of me get the final example on that page to work without glitches in my version of the code...)

- With the line uncommented, you can hold Alt and mouseDown on the canvas to pan until the circle lines up with the cursor to deselect it if the circle is too offset from the mouse position.
- With the line commented, the zoom works fine but panning still breaks the selection handle You have to look around the canvas for the handle.

Below is my example showing the zoom by itself. First I don't declare movedObject and the zoom keeps the mouse and circle aligned. Then I declare that variable and when I zoom and move the mouse, the circle seems to reset to the center of the canvas making it not match up with the mouse. I have a script running to show the mouseclicks.

[image: Zoom feature breaking when movedObject is defined]

[Here's my example showing panning](https://i.imgur.com/3CcO6DU.gifv) with and without that variable declared. The GIF was too large to embed, hence the link.

Additionally, I have a grid that I'd like to be able to snap the circle to. This seems to get all wonky as well if my mouse:move has any code in there to make it snap. Lines 147 and 148 would be something like:

```
movedObject.left=Math.round((opt.e.clientX -( movedObject.width/2) )/ grid) * grid /zoom;
movedObject.top = Math.round((opt.e.clientY - (movedObject.height/2) )/ grid) * grid/zoom;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just iterated through all possible mouse position options in my mouse:move function until I found something that worked. I could have sworn I tried all the options before with no luck, so I started keeping a list of results i.e.

```
pointer.x pointer.y = No Joy  
options.e.layerX and options.e.layerY  = No Joy 
canvas._offset.left, canvas._offset.top   = No Joy 
options.clientX,  options.clientY  = No Joy
```

After trying a variety of pointer position options that DON'T work, I believe I found the answer. The solution is to use absolutePosition.x and absolutePosition.y in the calculation.

```
movedObject.left= (Math.round((options.absolutePointer.x - movedObject.width / 2) / grid) * grid);
movedObject.top = (Math.round((options.absolutePointer.y - movedObject.height / 2)/ grid) * grid);
```

Now regardless of zoom factor or pan value, the part sticks to the mousepointer like I want.